# Kerberos authentication module with python

Tags: python, kerberos

I have a python program which accesses solr, although the service is protected by kerberos authentication. I have the kerberos module and I have found 
http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_kerberos.html

But I cannot make it work. Does anybody have any idea?

I am getting an error of:

```
kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
kerberos.GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Cannot determine realm for numeric host address', -1765328141))
```

Comment: You're gonna need to show what you have tried, what exactly goes wrong and how you tried to fix it. [Please read this page!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cannot determine realm for numeric host address`. I'm guessing that you're using a principal without a realm (eg: `myuser` instead of `myuser@MYREALM.EXAMPLE.COM`) and your kerberos server, your `KDC`, has been specified as an IP address. If you really need to use an IP address for some reason, I think you can map it to your realm in your `krb5.conf`. Or just use the realm name.

It would really help to see some code.

Comment: I changed according to your instructions and it worked. thank you